# Showing an inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, laplace-transform

I wish to show $$|{(Re^{i \theta})^{-\frac{1}{2}}}\exp(\frac{-1}{Re^{i \theta}})| < \frac{M}{R^k}$$ for some M, k > 0

I've managed to reduce it to $$|R^{-\frac{1}{2}}| |\exp(\frac{-1}{Re^{i \theta}})|$$
but am unsure of where to go from here.

In context, I'm trying to find the inverse Laplace transform of $s^{\frac{-1}{2}}\exp(\frac{-1}{s})$ using the complex inversion formula. Any help at all is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints :

If $a$ and $b$ are two real numbers,

$$\left|\exp(a+ib)\right|=\exp(a)$$

If $\theta$ is a real number, $R>0$ :

$$-\dfrac 1{Re^{i\theta}}=-\dfrac 1R e^{-i\theta}=-\dfrac 1R \cos(\theta)+\dfrac iR\sin(\theta)$$

Comment: So I now have $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{R}} \exp(-\frac{1}{R} \cos(\theta))$$

How do I obtain an M and k from this?

Comment: In which interval is your $\theta$?

Comment: $0 < \theta < \pi$

Comment: In this case, if $R\geqslant 1$, $\exp(-\frac 1R\cos(\theta))\leqslant 1\exp(\frac 1R)\leqslant \exp(1)$.